# Vue template render without all the extra

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a very, very simple set of Vue components that all work. These are a simple addition on top of an existing C# app.

At the moment, these are .html files (brought into the app inside `<script>` tags) and .js files loaded by reference.

These all work, are very light weight, and I love it.

Now I want to compile the HTML for each component into a Vue render function, and the .js into one minified .js file.

The .js to .min.js is pretty standard, but I cannot figure out how to get the HTML to compile into the Vue render function. Everything I've found involves a LOT of overhead and [running a web server](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/getting-started-with-vue-single-file-components-using-webpack-2ae078058688) which seems a massive overkill for an `html->script` transform, and I don't need a full web application spun up. I only need my existing, simple templates transformed to something more friendly for production than my long-form html templates getting dumped to the page.

I'm not entirely opposed to turning the .html+.js into .vue files, but just doing that doesn't seem to overcome my issue.

Comment: Will you completely against to use webpack for this job? https://webpack.js.org/

Comment: @Adriano I'm not opposed to using webpack, npm/webpack is probably the solution somehow, but the "big" vue webpack packages are way overkill - unless I'm wrong about how to use them.

Comment: If you really need to stick a nail in the wall, sometimes what you need is just a hammer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot figure out how to get the HTML to compile into the Vue render function

To generate a render function from a Vue template string (e.g., read from an HTML file), you could use [`vue-template-compiler`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-template-compiler) like this:

```js
const compiler = require('vue-template-compiler')
const output = compiler.compile('<div>{{msg}}</div>')
console.log(output) // => { render: "with(this){return _c('div',[_v(_s(msg))])}" }
```

> Everything I've found involves a LOT of overhead and running a web server which seems a massive overkill for an `html->script` transform

The "web server" you mention is provided by [Webpack CLI](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/), and is intended to faciliate development. You don't *need* to use the dev server. The article indeed describes several steps in manually setting up a project to build Vue single-file-components, but a simpler method is to use [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/) to automatically scaffold such a project.